# How can I get the json data in an array in an array in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to get the data in android studio with Wordpress rest api. But I can't get the data in an array that is inside a series. I tried the for loop but it didn't work. The underlined series in the image below is the category name and is variable. I want to get the name name: data under this series, but I failed. I will be glad if you help me.

[image]

```
final String GET_URL = Server.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + Server.SERVER_URL + Get.SERVER_JSON_RECENTLY_POSTS;

        Log.d("serverurl", GET_URL);


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                if (!response.equals(null)) {

                    Log.d("Your Array Response", response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Get.SERVER_JSON_RECENTLY_POSTS_ARRAY);

                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {

                            Log.d("jsonarrays", String.valueOf(jsonArray) + j);


                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            JSONObject jsonObjects = jsonObject.getJSONObject("categories");
                            JSONObject jsonObjects2 = jsonObjects.getJSONObject("name");

                             Log.d("jsonobjects", String.valueOf(jsonObjects2));
}

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Your error",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                else {
                    Log.d("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
                }
```

Comment: Can you show the entire structure of json? Raw json, not processed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend you name your variables according to what they mean in the JSON, it will make things a lot easier for you (and us) to visualize.

It seems like your categories is an array as well and inside your for loop, you are not iterating through it. Your variable that holds the categories should be JSONArray, and position 0 of the array would be the JSONObject you are trying to get.

If I understand your code correctly, `jsonObjects` should be the array I'm talking about, iterate through it and try getting the property your want from the JSONObjects inside.